# Execute SQL Task within SSIS Broken

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I'm trying to add an "Execute SQL Task" step to a new SSIS package, and I get the following message when trying to open it.

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2022, with Visual Studio 2022 with SQL Data Tools installed.  I've tried this on 3 different workstations, and I receive the same message on each one.  I'm also unable to open the task on any existing packages as well.  What am I missing?

I've tried uninstalling Visual Studio 2022 and reinstalling it.  I've tried multiple different machines.  I've also made sure that VisStudio 2022 is the only version that's installed.

EDIT:  This works fine in Visual Studio 2019; I'm able to open the "Execute SQL Task" control just fine, even on the machines that are affected by this in VisStudio 2022. I wonder if I've stumbled across a bug with SSIS in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this but I'm using SQL Server 2019. However I had similiar Problems in Visual Studio 2022 after I installed the SSIS Extension. I think it is a bug in the SSIS Extension which hasn't been on the market for long.

Comment: Did you try to modify the SSIS SOlution in order to run as 2019 package? If you go to the proberties of your solution there should be something like "target server version" or something - helped me many times when I installed a newer version of VS than the solution was built in.

Comment: Tyron, yes, I tried changing the target server version to both 2019 and 2022.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue.  Please read the following article on "SSIS Projects extension for VS2022 troubleshooting guide".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/release-notes-integration-services-2022?view=sql-server-ver16

Version 0.3...

Can't edit Execute SQL Task when SQL Server 2022 is installed at the same machine
Edit Execute SQL Task shows error: "'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTaskExecuteSQLTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version-16.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is not registered for use on this computer."
Workaround: Executing with non-admin user might solve the issue. If not, SQL Server 2022 & VS extension for SSIS have to be installed on separate machines for now. We are working on the fix.